# Can't submit my default HTML form in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, submit

I am trying to navigate via form on an external site, like the PayPal donations link. The sample Code of PayPal did not work, so I was trying to make the code more easy.
The easiest code of a form opening in a new tab, I could imagine is the following:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.de" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="myTest" value="value">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I do not know what am I doing wrong? Its not working.

Comment: Your code in the snippet works fine when put in an html-file. It opens a new tab and passes the parameters in  the request.

Comment: is there any error you see on the console?

Comment: Here is list of errors

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2020080501.js?21067093:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
42Blocked opening '<URL>' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Comment: try add `ngNoForm` to get a "HTML form": `<form ngNoForm action="https://www.google.de" target="_blank">...<form>`

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks man, this seems to help. If you provide your comment as an answer, I will take it as solution and upvote it! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @eliseo mentioned in the comments. The solution to this problem is the following:

Add `ngNoForm` to get a "HTML form": `<form ngNoForm action="https://www.google.de" target="_blank">...<form>`